# Printing a variable only when it changes?

Tags: php, postgresql

First off, my question was a little vague or confusing since I'm not really sure how to phrase my question to be specific. I'm trying to query a database of stockists for a Knitting company (school project using PHP) but I'm looking to print the city as a heading instead of with each stockists information.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mc16korustockists where locale = 'south'";
    $result = pg_exec($sql);
    $nrows = pg_numrows($result);
    print $nrows;
    $items = pg_fetch_all($result);
    print_r($items);

for ($i=0; $i<$nrows2; $i++) {
    print "<h2>";
        print $items[$i]['city'];
    print "</h2>";

    print $items[$i]['name'];
    print $items[$i]['address'];
    print $items[$i]['city'];
    print $items[$i]['phone'];

    print "<br />";    
    print "<br />";
```

}

I'm querying the database for all of the data in it, the rows being ref, name, address, city and phone, and executing it. Querying the number of rows then using that to determine how many iterations for the loop to run is all fine but what I'd like to have is for the h2 heading to appear above the for ($i=0;) line.

Trying just breaks my page so that might be out of the question. I figure I'd have to count the number of entries in 'city' until it detects a change then change the heading to that name I think? That or make a heap of queries and set a variable for each name but at point, I might as well do it manually (and I highly doubt it would be best practice). Oh, and I'd welcome any critiques to my PHP since I'm just starting out.

Thanks and if you need any more information, just ask!

P.S. Our class is learning with PostgreSQL instead of MySQL as you can see in the tags.

Comment: Great to see people teaching with PostgreSQL. You'll be learning fewer bad habits as a consequence. Please mention your PostgreSQL version in questions, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problems:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mc16korustockists where locale = 'south' order by city";

...


$city = '';

for ($i=0; $i<$nrows2; $i++) {
    if($items[$i]['city']!=$city)
    {
        print "<h2>";
            print $items[$i]['city'];
        print "</h2>";
        $city = $items[$i]['city'];
    }
    print $items[$i]['name'];
    print $items[$i]['address'];
    print $items[$i]['city'];
    print $items[$i]['phone'];

    print "<br />";    
    print "<br />";
}
```

Comment: If an answer is correct, please mark as so, otherwise stackoverflow won't ever know that your problem has been solved. Consider up vote answers that were somewhat useful. This helps other users with similar questions to find answers more easily

Answer (score 0):

Look at the previous item and check if it's the same city - if not, or it there is no previous item, new city !

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is keep track of when the city changes and print it when it changes.

I have tried to keep the code as similar as possible to what you provided so you can see where the changes happen.

```
// store previous city, set to NULL by default so the first city from the result set will always be printed 
// (assuming that the first city from the result set is not null).

$previous_city = NULL;

for ($i=0; $i<$nrows2; $i++) {

   // determine what the city is from the current row
   // creating a separate variable for this is not really necessary, but helps to make the example clearer
   $current_city = $items[$i]['city'];

   // check if current city is different to the one in the previous row
   if ($previous_city != $current_city) {
    // city is different, lets print it
    print "<h2>";
        print $items[$i]['city'];
    print "</h2>";
    }

    print $items[$i]['name'];
    print $items[$i]['address'];
    print $items[$i]['city'];
    print $items[$i]['phone'];

    print "<br />";    
    print "<br />";

    // end of loop, the current city, now becomes the previous city
    $previous_city = $items[$i]['city'];
```

}

Please Note, you also need to ORDER BY city in your SQL so that all the items from 1 city are grouped together, otherwise this method won't work